# Xcode can I animate UITabBarItem image in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I would like to know if I can animate image in `UITabBarItem`.

I would like to achieve "Springboard" effect, just like the one on the iPhone main screen for managing apps.

I have five items in my `UITabBar` and I would like to animate only item two, three and four.

Is this possible?

I tried with `layer` property but it seems that `UITabBarItem` doesn't have one.

Thank You.

Comment: nothing is impossible except NOTHING...